# Does mint plant affect guppies?

Tags: aquarium, fish, safety, poison, plants

Can I try the step 1 and 2 posted [here](https://www.gardenersworld.com/how-to/grow-plants/how-to-grow-mint-from-cuttings/) with a fish tank of guppies:

1. Cutting a stem of mint;
2. Placing mint stems in a <s>glass of water</s> fish tank containing guppies?

Will guppies enjoy the mint plant? Is mint plant harmful to guppies?

Comment: the acctive chemical in mint is an oil,and is most likely toxic to fish.

Comment: @trondhansen Thanks! I avoid placing Mint cuttings inside the fish tank for now =)